# What does the "Scavenging" stat do? How useful is it?

Tags: the-division

One of the stats that can appear on medium to high level armor in The Division is "Scavenging". That game doesn't really explain what exactly this stat does. Is it useful? If so, in what situations?

Comment: If I had to guess - more or better quality crafting materials when looting the areas in the overworked that have them. Not sure of this though.

Comment: That sounds reasonable - it's what I figured. I'm very curious about the underlying mechanics though.

Comment: Yep, I've kind of equated it to magic find % in other loot games.

Comment: If you ever wonder what a stat means, look at the character tab in your menu.  There is usually a better description than the one word names, as well as some information about what the numbers translate into, ie +X armor is Y% damage reduction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually is something like +x % for Magic find. It increases your Chance to loot better gear, techs etc.
We compared in a group the various scavenger percentages. Overall, the higher, the better. Its really nice to get yellow tech, when you only get a green one, if you didnt give some % into scavenging.

Some Addition: Scavenging will not increase loot count. But it will increase the Chance, that your loot is of better quality (yellow instead of purple item, not 7% crit instead of 5,5%)

Comment: This is a good start, but it's still pretty vague. If you elaborated on this I would have no problem accepting it (or giving it a bounty).

Comment: Sure it is vague, im not a dataminer. Have you tried some items with +x to scavenging? On character window you can inspect your current bonus. One in the group got a +40 and was pretty comfortable with the loot.

Comment: I agree this is pretty vague. I wouldn't accept it. I guess I'll give it an upvote though. Somewhat useful.

Comment: I'd assume that if let's say you have 1% chance of getting gold drop, that with "scavenging +50%" you'd have 1.5% chance.

Comment: On the 'Character' tab in Inventory you can find a list of all the stats affecting your character and what they do. The description there for Gathering is pretty vague, but it agrees with this answer that it is basically magic find. I don't have it in front of me now, but I think it was close to "Increases the amount and quality of found items".

Answer (score -1):

There is actually another stat for that ("magix find"), it's a Talent but I can't remember what it's called, it's on a Orange/Yellow item that's being sold right now at lvl 30 in the Base of Operations.

Answer (score -2):

actually the real answer to this question is SCAVENGING is for finding materials and items like med kits, grenade drops, ITEM FIND, which is a talent on high end gold knee pads is for finding items such as gold items

Comment: There is no talent called 'Item Find' that I can see on any gear items, do you have an example?

Answer (score -4):

the talent is called perceptive i have it on my knee pads it gives +25% to item find and dz currency